# Bootstrap Reveal Footer Fixed not working on Safari

Tags: css, safari, footer, fixed

I have an issue with my Sticky Footer at the bottom.
It works fine on all browser but not on Safari...why?? :(

```
#main{
background-color: #f0f0f0;
box-shadow: 0px 20px 30px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 250px;
}

footer {
height: 250px;
z-index: -100;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it!
Just add this code... ;)

```
html, body{
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks anyway.